# spring validation how do I get validation results?

Tags: spring, validation

code  as follows:

```
....
@RequestMapping( "/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseTO test(
            @Valid  @RequestBody RequestTO to, HttpServletResponse resp)
    {
           //how do I get validation results here?
        return new ResponseTO("111");
    }

  @InitBinder
  protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
      binder.setValidator(new TestValidator());
  }




class TestValidator implements Validator {

    /**
    * This Validator validates just Person instances
    */
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return RequestTO.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
        RequestTO tx = (RequestTO) obj;
        if (tx.getName().equals("buy")) {
            e.rejectValue("feature", "NOT BUY");
        } 
    }
}
```

The part I could not figure out is how do I can get the validation results in the controller? Thanks!

Comment: You are probably mixing the Spring validation and JSR validations(@Valid). See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080684/spring-validator-having-both-annotation-and-validator-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sunil have mentioned you are mixing two approaches

If you want to use JSR303 Bean validations, you can define constraints of bean fields like

```
public class Customer {

    @NotEmpty //make sure name is not empty
    String name;

    @Range(min = 1, max = 150) //age need between 1 and 150
    int age;
 }
```

`@valid` is used to validate bean fields and you can get the errors using `BindingResult` like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCustomer(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "SignUpForm";
        } else {
            return "Done";
        }
    }
```

Check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/) for more details.

Or you can implement `Validator` and define `validate` method (As you have mentioned in your question).
Then you have to invoke the `validate` method, pass `BindingResult` object and add erros if present. Then you can check the `BindingResult` object for any errors.
For ex.

```
new TestValidator ().validate(requestTO , bindingResult); // invoking validate method
```

and  check for errors

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
  // Errors are present do something here
}
else
{
  // All is well!!
}
```

Or you can define `validator` to particular bean spring config file. Check this [link](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks! one more question: what is the preferred way to invoke the validate method? is it possible to use the  @InitBinder to do that?

Comment: I think configuring through XML is good way (as it keeps the configuration separated from business logic). `@InitBinder`  dont seem to be a good choice.

Comment: would you be able to give me an example? I don't web pages in  that project it is all restful web services. Thanks

Comment: @Bobo: I have added few links in my answer.